# compiling SFML with g++ compiler through the terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, visual-studio-code, sfml

here is what I typed in the terminal:

```
g++ -g -I/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/include -L/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/lib -l libsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d virtual_field.cpp -o virtual_field
```

I am having trouble with this because it is telling me that that it cant find the libraries which included.

```
ld: library not found for -llibsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is the whole thing if you need more context:

```
Carloss-MacBook-Pro:src cjm10000$ g++ -g -I/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/include -L/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/lib -l libsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d virtual_field.cpp -o virtual_field
ld: library not found for -llibsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You should note that questions posted here will be seen by a significant number of regular users within seconds. Take more care before hitting the post button next time. Regarding your question: Are you sure you have installed all of these necessary dependencies at your development system?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, thanks for the advice. I am using VS code and there is no extension for SFML or anything so I am trying to compile and run this program manually through the terminal.

Comment: fyi looks like you are using clang (g++ is probably symlinked to it)

Comment: It looks like the last code snippet is completely unnecessary. It is a copy of the previous two.

Comment: It's a linkage error, can be many errors, a nice ways is check if you have all includes or library installed, and check if the flag with -l is realy that.
In documentation the flags are 
``` lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system ```
and if your lib is in non default place you need tell inside -L option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really too sure and I don't have a Mac, so I cannot really test it, but I think you might be able to just drop the dylib file ending and the lib in front and just use that after -l, like you do with the other ones.

Something along the lines of this:
`g++ -g -I/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/include -L/Users/cjm10000/Desktop/7701X/code/include/SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d virtual_field.cpp -o virtual_field`

**Edit**

I looked up the section on the man page for `ld`, which does the actual linking and it says:

> -l namespec
>   --library=namespec
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to  link.  This option may be used any number of times.  If
>   namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for
>   a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for
>   a file called libnamespec.a.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for files other than libnamespec.a.  Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.  (By
>   convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.)  Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a
>   file called filename.

So you could have used the format `-l:libsfml-graphics.2.4.2.dylib` it seems. Note that this is from the man page of ld running on a GNU/linux system, so they do not mention dylib, as it seems to be a Mac specific file format.

Comment: thanks for the help, didn't know you didn't need file extension :D